# Recursive deallocation of larger tries

Tags: recursion, memory, memory-management, segmentation-fault, trie

I have written a basic function for recursively deallocating a trie data structure in C:

```
// Root pointer is passed as arg in initial call
void destroy(node *trav)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (trav->children[i])
        {
            destroy(trav->children[i]);
        }
    }

    free(trav);
}
```

This functions seems to work perfectly fine with any smaller dictionary file. The largest file that the program successfully loaded and unloaded contained 134,480 words.

However, it produces a segmentation fault when deallocating a larger trie. The larger file that causes a segmentation fault contains 506,915 words.

The error message produced by Valgrind states: "Invalid read of size 8" followed by several backtraces and finally; "Address  is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd".

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What might be causing this?

Stack overflow might be causing this, although that seems somewhat unlikely: there are almost no locals, so each frame probably only consumes 32 bytes of stack, and that would allow recursion of 8M/32 == 262144 levels deep with Linux default 8MiB stack.

However, if your trie is extremely unbalanced, stack overflow is possible.

You can try `ulimit -s unlimited` and see if that makes the problem go away.

Or you could run your program under GDB, and examine the instruction at which the  `SIGSEGV` is reported. If it's a `CALL`, `PUSH`, or another form of "move to stack", stack overflow is also very likely.

Comment: My resource limit is already set to maximum. How can I use GDB in such a way that it identifies the cause of the segmentation fault? It simply says that the program received signal SIGSEGV when I run it through GDB.

Comment: @GabrielSaul `gdb --args /path/to/exe arg1 ...`. You may also want to read https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html for introduction -- it will sever you well.

Comment: Much apologies. It turns out one of my buffer variables wasn't large enough to handle a certain string. Thanks for the resource though!

Comment: @GabrielSaul You should look into building your program with address sanitizer (https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) -- chances are this was not the *only* bug of this kind, and even if it was, testing with `-fsanitize=address` is a very good habit.